# Apply a monte carlo simulation on a pandas dataframe and return probability result in column

Tags: python, pandas, montecarlo

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'Name': ['Jim', 'Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim', 'Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim'], 'Predict': [2.901826509,3.212149337,2.388237651,3.744206058,1.944415024,2.719441794,2.543629608,3.264809759,3.661189232,2.509445492,4.784738653,3.305165944,4.03919276,2.708492579,3.172120051,
1.774120629,4.40550619,2.426048696,3.767313548,4.108914912,3.198379034,4.078331863,3.652025]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Mean'] = 4
df['StDev'] = 6
df.head(5)

    Name    Predict   Mean  StDev
0   Jim     2.901827    4   6
1   Jim     3.212149    4   6
2   Jim     2.388238    4   6
3   Jim     3.744206    4   6
4   Jim     1.944415    4   6
```

I am hoping to apply a simulation (10,000 maybe) across each `Predict` value to get a probability of the prediction being less than or equal to 0. I would like to add this as a column in that same dataframe.

I have done a basic work around version in excel by using the formula:

```
=NORM.INV(RAND(),"Predict","StDev")
```

But Im looking for a way to scale this through python.

Can anybody help with this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  If `Predict` is 2.90 in some row then the probability of it being less than 0 is 0.  If you want the % of the time that `Predict` is less than 0 you can just have `(df.Predict < 0).mean()`.

Comment: each row is a prediction of a different event. So my prediction is a point (e.g 2.90) however i do understand that my model has error in it so i was hoping to somehow simulate and work out how many times it goes below zero. I hope that helps? @KyleParsons