# Apply a function across all rows in new column creation Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset where i make my predictions and historically i know the standard deviations on these predictions:

```
d = {'Name': ['Jim', 'Matt','Alex','Nathan','Dom'], 'Predict': [2.901826509,3.212149337,2.388237651,3.744206058,1.944415024]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Mean'] = 4
df['StDev'] = 6
df.head(5)

    Name    Predict   Mean  StDev
0   Jim     2.901827    4   6
1   Matt    3.212149    4   6
2   Alex   2.388238    4   6
3   Nathan  3.744206    4   6
4   Dom     1.944415    4   6
```

I have also found a function from https://towardsdatascience.com/monte-carlo-simulation-and-variants-with-python-43e3e7c59e1f

That has the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def MC_prob(M,mu,sigma):
    prob_larger_than3 = []

    for i in range(M):
        # Using CDF since P[Z>=3] = 1-P[Z<=3]
        p = 1- norm.cdf(3, mu, sigma)
        # Using Survival Function P[Z>=3]
        p = norm.sf(3, mu, sigma)
        prob_larger_than3.append(p)
    MC_approximation_prob = np.array(prob_larger_than3).mean()
    return(MC_approximation_prob)

MC_prob(M = 10000, mu = 10, sigma = 2)
0.9997673709209641
```

I would like to apply this function and create a new column in my dataframe, with the probability of my `Predict` column being over 3.

I tried:

```
df['ProbOver3'] = MC_prob(M = 10000, mu = df.Predict, sigma = df.StDev)
```

but it gave the same value for every for row. Any ideas on how to apply this over every row? Essentially I am trying to simulate and return a probability of each row being above or below certain numbers and I hope I am on the right track. It's a Follow up question to this one [Apply a monte carlo simulation on a pandas dataframe and return probability result in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69224300/apply-a-monte-carlo-simulation-on-a-pandas-dataframe-and-return-probability-resu?noredirect=1#comment122357663_69224300)

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `df.apply()` with a lambda. You can apply (pun intended) this function to every row to make a new column by adding the `axis=1` which specifies every row. Then use a lambda to pass the row to the function. Here is how you could use this:

```py
df['ProbOver3'] = df.apply(lambda row: MC_prob(10000, row['Predict'], row['StDev']), axis=1)
```

Checkout the docs on [df.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for more info.